# Обнуление количества вызовов при тестировании

Tags: java, тестирование, mockito

Есть следующий код. В нем проверяется количество вызовов функции `oneFunc`.

```
one = spy(one);
one.oneFunc(" ");
verify(one, times(1)).oneFunc(anyString());
one.oneFunc(" ");
verify(one, times(2)).oneFunc(anyString());
```

Можно ли как-то обнулить количество вызовов, чтобы вызовы считались с последнего обнуления? Т.е. как-то так:

```
one = spy(one);
one.oneFunc(" ");
verify(one, times(1)).oneFunc(anyString());
//Строка, обнуляющая количество
one.oneFunc(" ");
verify(one, times(1)).oneFunc(anyString());
```

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но вы пробовали создавать новый spy?

Comment: В моем случае нет возможности создать новый `spy` в силу структуры теста. Мне нужно именно обнулить счетчик.

Comment: Тогда у вас неправильный тест) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090317/resetting-mockito-spy

Comment: @Vartlok а в сем заключается его неправильность? И да, спасибо за ссылку, `Mockito.reset(one);` - это то, что мне нужно было.

Comment: В том, что тест должен тестировать одну, выделенную часть, это же unit тесты, а не интеграционные. И если вам надо ресетить мок, значит тест слишком большой и его надо бы разбить. По ссылке про это сказано.